# Ruby Status Bar with Sleep

Tags: ruby, command-line, sleep

I have a pomodoro timer client functioning from my terminal. I want to add a status bar with hash marks **(#)**.

For example, I want to use a loop for each 25 minute interval. I want to print a '#' and have the program sleep for 60 seconds. After 60 seconds, I want it to go back through the loop and print another '#' and sleep again but when I run the program I see a welcome message but then it ends the program.

**Ruby**:

```
def period(t, message)
  puts "#{message} #{t / 60} min.".colorize( color )
  put "Status: "
  time_left = t / 60    # Convert to minutes
  (0..time_left).each do |minute|
    put "#"
    sleep 60
  end
end
```

Any suggestions are welcome as I'm stumped. Help!

Comment: you see a welcome message ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it might have been the value for t which gives 0 from t/60.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler):

```
require 'rufus/scheduler'
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
scheduler.every '60s' do
  putc "#"
end
scheduler.join
```